# PyMySQL returns bytes instead of str

Tags: python, pymysql

Here is a simple example of using pymysql (Python 3):

```
import pymysql
conn = pymysql.connect(user='admin', passwd='...', host='host', use_unicode=True)
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute("SELECT category FROM product LIMIT 0,1")
print (type(c.fetchone()[0]))
```

It returns

> <class 'bytes'>

The type of the field is **varchar** and I thought if I specify **use_unicode=True** it shoud return field value as **str** instead of **bytes**. Yes, I do know that I can convert bytes to str, but I don't want to.

Is it possible to get str right away? What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was in the field's collation. Since it was set to **utf8_bin** pymysql counted it as [binary](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/charset-binary-collations.html) in spite of it was **varchar**. Changing the collation to **utf8_general_ci** solved the problem.

Comment: Where did you make this change?  In the pymysql connection?

Comment: No, I changed collation of a table column.